# Can you use Cortana only with xaml project? or regular C# is ok too?

Tags: c#, xaml, cortana

I am trying to use Cortana in my small C# project.
So I have been reading plenty of tutorials.

I have created a Voice Command vcd file with a very simply command in it.
All the samples/tutorials I found mention that you need to install the command definition when the app is navigated to.

ex:

- https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2016/06/30/how-to-integrate-cortana-with-a-windows-10-uwp-app-in-c/)
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3789b7/how-to-integrate-cortana-in-the-menu-app/

I cannot override 'OnNavigatedTo' nor 'OnActivated' because they does not exist in my project.
And I do not have a App.xaml.cs

I am guessing I could use some other event, but I do not know which one would be better.

Is it actually possible to use Cortana if you do not use a Xaml project ?
If so, how ?

Comment: As the first link says "We need to add those [voice command] definitions at application start up" - so use whatever is appropriate for your app type, which you haven't specified.

Comment: Well I have decided, I am making a C# DirectX app. But that type of application is pure C#, no XAML. That's why I was not sure if I could use Cortana with it. I will try to load it in some of the starting events of the app .